# como agregar tabpage en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Alguien podría asesorarme como crear tabPage en tiempo de ejecución es decir que al dar clic me abra una nueva pestaña, uso controles de DevExpress
solo instancio el componente y utilizo sus propiedades y se crea el tab pero no se como hacerlo de manera dinámica.

```
        ASPxPageControl pageControl = new ASPxPageControl();
        pageControl.ID = "pageControl";
        this.Page.Form.Controls.Add(pageControl);
        pageControl.TabPages.Add("tabs1", "tabs1.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré algo parecido a lo que buscas.. igual te puede servir o dar una idea... también te puede ayudar usar una función en JS con Ajax.

[PageControl dinamico](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4864/pagecontrol-how-to-dynamically-add-remove-tab-pages)